# Should a web api return status errors to the client applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Please see the code below:

```
public async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPeople()
        {
            var uri = API.People.GetAllPeople(_remoteServiceBaseUrl);
            try
            {
                var responseString = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
                var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(responseString);
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Redirect to error webpage
            }

        }
```

I am using Identity Server 4 for authentication and authorisation facilities in the web app and web api.

Say the Web API requires administrator users only and the user calling the web api is not an administrator, then a HttpRequestException is caught by the MVC caller.  How should this scenario be handled? Is it enough just to put an Administrator Authorize attribute on the MVC method (GetAllPeople) and forget it or is there a more elegant way to do this i.e. remove the try catch?

Comment: If a method is intended to be called by certain roles, use an Authorize attribute. The call could fail due to many other stuff, however. Also, IDS is **not** an authorization server, only an authentication server.

Answer (score 0):

It is not convenient to redirect user to error page in every method. You can add exception handler middleware to pipeline and configure it to catch error, log it and show default error page. Read this for more details:

- [UseExceptionHandler Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.exceptionhandlerextensions.useexceptionhandler?view=aspnetcore-2.1)
- [StatusCodePagesExtensions.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.statuscodepagesextensions.usestatuscodepageswithreexecute?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

As for you main question - it will be enough to user AuthorizeAttribute in case if default error handling is properly configured.